# $.Get method withinin each() loop doesn't holds

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

On a DropDown select, i run the following jquery, I am using each() to iterate through an `li`.

My `$.get()` takes some time to bring data from server, so i am using loading img by toggling it. but `each` method doesn't wait till `get` brings the data, it directly jumps to the end.

How to hold this `each` till the `get` brings data from server?

JQUERY

```
jd('#UserId').change(function (e) {
            var selectedID = jd(this).val();                
            jd('.loading').css("display", "block");
            jd(".stats_box li").each(function (index, liElement) {
                var li_id = liElement.id;

                /* Request the partial view with .get request. */
                jd.get('/Home/_CaseStatus?type=CaseStatus&user_id=' + selectedID, function (data) {                    

                    jd('#CaseStatus').html(data);

                });
            });
            alert("End"); 
            jd('.loading').css("display", "none");
        });
```

On running above Jquery, it directly shows me `alert` & then the data is seen after sometime.

Comment: It's **asynchronous**, you shouldn't have to "hold" it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wait till all the requests are completed

```
jd('#UserId').change(function (e) {
    var selectedID = jd(this).val();
    jd('.loading').css("display", "block");
    var rqts = [];
    jd(".stats_box li").each(function (index, liElement) {
        var li_id = liElement.id;
        rqts.push(jd.get('/Home/_CaseStatus?type=CaseStatus&user_id=' + selectedID, function (data) {
            //I've a doubt about the target element
            jd('#CaseStatus').html(data);
        }));
    });
    //wait for all requests to complete
    jd.when.apply(jd, rqts).always(function () {
        jd('.loading').css("display", "none");
    })
});
```

---

As meagar suggested, it will be better to use .map()

```
jd('#UserId').change(function (e) {
    var selectedID = jd(this).val();
    jd('.loading').css("display", "block");
    var rqts = jd(".stats_box li").map(function (liElement, index) {
        var li_id = liElement.id;
        return jd.get('/Home/_CaseStatus?type=CaseStatus&user_id=' + selectedID, function (data) {
            //I've a doubt about the target element
            jd('#CaseStatus').html(data);
        });
    });
    //wait for all requests to complete
    jd.when.apply(jd, rqts).always(function () {
        jd('.loading').css("display", "none");
    })
});
```

Comment: please replace $ with jd in your answer

Comment: Better to use `.map` instead of `.each` though; `rqts = jd("...").map(function () { return $.get... })`

Comment: @meagar yes... it will be

Comment: Nice...Worked Accurately..!!

Answer (score 1):

use **[$.when](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)** at the time of ajax in loop

and  wait until all the requests are completed

see below

```
var work_list=[];

jd('#UserId').change(function (e) {
            var selectedID = jd(this).val();                
            jd('.loading').css("display", "block");
            jd(".stats_box li").each(function (index, liElement) {
                var li_id = liElement.id;
            /* Request the partial view with .get request. */
          work_list.push( jd.get('/Home/_CaseStatus?type=CaseStatus&user_id=' + selectedID, function (data) { 
                jd('#CaseStatus').html(data);

            }));

         //now it  wait for all requests to complete then come in done()                
        jd.when.apply(jd, work_list).done(function() {
              alert( "end" );
            });
        });

        jd('.loading').css("display", "none");
    });
```

Comment: @meagar i have use many time so i am sure if you know some better then plz share with us :)

Comment: Look at where it is. It's *inside* the `.each`, so you're doing `when` every iteration. It's supposed to happen once after *all* iterations.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but declaring work_list before `change` event didn't gave me perfect results. After including it within `change` worked perfectly.